# wxWidgets: wxButton with both bitmap and text

Tags: button, bitmap, wxwidgets

I want my `wxButton` to have a black background and white text for it's label. I tried [this sample code](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxBitmapButton) only I also tried it with `wxButton` and `SetBitmapLabel`.

All I could manage was to get the bitmap to display, however I also want the button's text (label) to be displayed over the bitmap at the same time. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what do you want to use a bitmap at all if just want to display the text. What's wrong with just doing

```
wxButton* b = new wxButton(...); // possibly use wxBORDER_NONE style
b->SetBackgroundColour(*wxBLACK);
b->SetForegroundColour(*wxWHITE);
```

?

Also notice that since wxWidgets 3.0 the functionality of `wxBitmapButton` is available in `wxButton` itself, i.e. you can set a bitmap for any button and it will be displayed in addition to the text.

Comment: thanks, I am quite new to wxWidgets and this slipped past me. Now it works just how I want